# restrict possible combination of Flags

Tags: c#, enum-flags

is there a way to combine flags within an Enum but to restrict the possible combinations? 
I have an enum like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum CopyFlags
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Copy members regardless of their actual case
    /// </summary>
    CaseSensitive = 1,
    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates if a leading underscore (e.g. _myMember) should be ignored while comparing member-names.
    /// </summary>
    IgnoreLeadingUnderscore = 2,
    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates if only properties should be copied. Usefull when all technical data is stored in properties. 
    /// </summary>
    PropertiesOnly = 4
}
```

Now I want to also introduce a `FieldsOnly`-value but ensure that it is only used when `PropertiesOnly` is not present. Is this possible?

Comment: No, there is nothing you can prevent this. Even `(CopyFlags) 12345` is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. It's not even possible to restrict the values to being the items listed. For example, the following is allowed in C#:

```
CopyFlags flags = (CopyFlags)358643;
```

You need to perform your validation explicitly inside of the methods which include a `CopyFlags` parameter.

Comment: So I should introduce FieldsOnly with value 8 and then check for Properties & Fields, right?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible within the context of the enum; instead, you'd have to validate it:

```
public void DoSomething(CopyFlag flag)
{
   if (flag.HasFlag(CopyFlags.PropertiesOnly) && flag.HasFlag(CopyFlags.FieldsOnly))
      throw new ArgumentException();

}
```

Comment: Then use `(flag & CopyFlags.PropertiesOnly) == CopyFlags.PropertiesOnly or (flag & CopyFlags.FieldOnly) == CopyFlags.FieldOnly`.  That method was a shortcut for that.